# Autocomplete Improvement

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to implement a feature for Textbox Autocomplete. Currently I using jQuery Autocomplete but I am unable to implement a functionality which is related to search delay; For example if I search for "New ", I will have an autocomplete list having [ 'New York','New South Memphis' .....]
Now, if I press "S" and immediately hit down arrow then I end up with selecting the first item ie 'New York' rather than getting results for cities starting with "New S". [A Web service call of search cities starting with 'New S' gets triggered]
What I want to achieve is to block the down arrow till the results are retrieved. If anyone can explain what I should focus to achieve this feature or is it not possible due to asynchronous nature of the Web Service call ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#locations").keydown(function() {

        var keyword = $("#locations").val();
        var url = 'http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?format=json&cb=myCallbackFn&query=' + keyword;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            async: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    });



});

var myCallbackFn = function(data) {
    var cities = [];
    for (i = 0; i < data.RESULTS.length; i++) {
        if (data.RESULTS[i].type == 'city') {
            cities.push(data.RESULTS[i].name);
        }
    }

    $("#locations").autocomplete({
        source: cities
    }).autocomplete("widget").addClass("fixed-height");
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
  
  <style>
    .fixed-height {
     padding: 1px;
     max-height: 200px;
     overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Autocomplete: </label>
      <input id="locations" type="text" size="50"/>
        </div>   
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you try by adding this to first line of keydown event listener $('#locations').autocomplete("destroy");

Answer (score 0):

One way of completing this would be to either remove all the autocomplete suggestions when a new GET request for the suggestions is fired, or alternatively, set a flag to ignore down arrow keypresses until the request has resolved.

Comment: Is there a possibility that I can use promises to wait till the request is resolved ?

Comment: Yes - that is what promises are intended for.